# How to push single file in git

Tags: django, git, heroku, django-admin

I want to push a single or few files to my website in git. I do it everytime by following way -

```
git add (file)
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

The problem is that `git push heroku master` also changes other things on my website by replacing it with old one, for example - "replacing admin objects with old one which is in django server". Is there any way to push it for only single file ?

Comment: If you use `-am` in `git commit` it will commit all changes for all files. You should run `git commit -m "make it better"` for only the file you added using the `git add (file)` command.

Comment: don't use option `-a ` because this mean "add all changes to the commit".

Comment: You are using `-a` causing everything that is tracked to be committed. Also as per your previous question I had advised you to add your database file (I assume to be `db.sqlite3`) to gitignore.

Comment: You can't (push one file): `git push` operates on *commits*, not files. (Well, you *can* push a commit that contains exactly one file, but that won't do what you intended.) As everyone else said, make the commit with `git commit`, which lets you carefully arrange, on the "stage", the set of files that you want to go into that commit. The `git status` command *describes* the stage by telling you which files, if any, have been changed; the files that haven't been changed, are the same as before, on the stage as in the *current* commit.